# Windows program doesn't run on another computer when a DLL attached

Tags: c#, c++, windows

A windows program compiled using VS 2015 on Win10 64-bit (target x86) has several DLLs (C++, OpenGL) linked to it, and while it runs on Win10 64-bit and on Win7 32-bit desktops (both of which have VS installed), it doesn't run on a laptop without VS.

So I wrote 3 versions of a test program:

1. a command-line program in C++ / OpenGL, just a GL window with a red rectangle;
2. a windows program with just a window and a button which doesn't do anything;
3. a windows program with a window and the button which when clicked brings up the GL window with the rectangle.

As far as the actual operations are concerned, all three are exactly the same, except for the presence of the DLL taking the place of the command-line version.

Compiling the release version for (1) and (2) is fine, they run on all 3 computers, including the laptop.

However, (3) runs on the Win10 and Win7 desktops, but not on the laptop. When clicking on the exe for the windows program on the laptop all that happens is the throbber coming on for half a second and then nothing.

Going by so many posts on the internet including SOF, I tried the following:

- making sure the DLL is exactly the same throughout (name, file size, date/time stamp);
- adding the appropriate version (debug, release) to the relevant compiles;
- using Dependencies to find the dlls associated with the windows program and the dll,   included

> basefx.dll
> DC120V154_32.dll
> fpxlib.dll
> gdi32.dll
> inetwh32.dll
> kernel32.dll
> mscoree.dll
> mscorlib.dll
> msvcp100.dll
> msvcp140d.dll
> msvcr100.dll
> opengl32.dll
> pcdlib32.dll
> PresentationCore.dll
> PresentationFramework.dll
> roboex32.dll
> shell32.dll
> System.dll
> System.Data.dll
> System.XML.dll
> ucrtbased.dll
> user32.dll
> vcruntime140d.dll
> in the folder where the exe and dll is (one suggestion on a Microsoft forum said to "simply drop" the required dll into the exe folder for local reference);

- set the properties under References in VS Solution Explorer to "Copy Local - True" (before they were all set to 'False');
- simply copied the contents of the debug folder into a separate folder to see what happens (I know, not a good technique but as such the program still worked on both desktops), but again nothing on the laptop.

Also, if I rename the DLL the symptom on the desktop is the same as on the laptop (throbber, then nothing), so it *seems* that's what happens when it can't find the dll.

So how to enable the windows exe to find the dll? Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear from your post but you should NOT try redistributing operating system DLLs when deploying.  If your program depends on those, then the target PC will need to install whatever package those DLLs come from (e.g. MSVC runtime or whatever)

Comment: if you run "depends" on the non-VS system it should highlight what's missing and then you can look up what package those missing DLLs come in

Comment: `msvcp140d.dll` (edit and `vcruntime140d.dll`) is one of the debug runtime support libraries and may not be distributed to a system without MSVS.  If you have this DLL (or others with a `*d.dll` name) you have a dependency on the debug runtime support.  You need to either build a release build (and check the dependencies) or install MSVS.  Also mixing the debug and release DLLs in the same process will have ABI issues as Microsoft change the layout of some of the Standard Library classes between debug and release.

Comment: M.M – haven’t run Dependencies on the laptop, that’s a good idea, will see what happens. 

As for trying with msvcp140d.dll (edit and vcruntime140d.dll), good point it shouldn’t be used, especially since the end user cannot be expected to have MSVS.

Anyway, will try to see what Depend. says on the laptop.

Comment: Perhaps there is just one little setting in the Configuration manager when compiling the C++ DLL for release I don’t know about?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Posted the solution but it got deleted for some reason. The main point: set in MSVS Property Pages > Configuration Properties > General > Use of MFC > Use MFC in a Shared DLL. It now runs on the laptop without MSVS.